# window.location.href works offline but anchor tag does not

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a progressive web app (PWA) that is usable offline.

On the page, I use the link to navigate back to the previous page like this.

`<a href="/alink">Back<a>`

It doesn't work but causes the `No Internet`.

On the other hand, the `window.location.href` does navigate to the previous page even when I'm offline.

Why does this happen? What is the difference between `a` tag and `window.location.href`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a` tag will redirect to the new page by going forward to it.
However the window.location.href will just change the route in the URL. But not actually redirect the page.

If you want to go back, try using the window history. As this is what things like react router use to move around different paths.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a great answer. However, do you know any anchor tag attribute that makes the `a` tag not redirect?

Answer (score 1):

The `a` tag always redirects you to a new page which is required a network connection. If you want to get back to the previous page with the `a` tag. You can use this

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a>
```

It will navigate you back to the cached page that you loaded before going offline.